# Notepad++ regex replace Css @media

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to clean out everything between `@media` and `}`. Only after research I still cannot find how. I want to replace everything between the **BOLD** text below, including the **BOLD** text itself:

```
@media all and (max-width: 240px)

{
  #toast-container>div
  {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 50px;
    width: 11em;
  }

  #toast-container .toast-close-button
  {
    right: -.2em;
    top: -.2em;
  };
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
  .lead
  {
    font-size: 19.5px;
  };
}
```

RESULT 1: `@media }`

RESULT 2: **nothing**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Replace Dialog(Ctrl+H), enable `Regular Expression` and `. matches newline`

Then, search for:

```
@media.*?\};.*?\}
```

or

```
@media.*?(\};)\s*?\}
```

And replace for empty string... (this will remove all - including bold text)

Let me know if it works.